# PhoneGap: Device orientation under iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I created a new PhoneGap app using the following

`phonegap create hello-world com.hello.world HelloWorld`

With PhoneGap 4.2.0-0.25.0. However, I am not able to change the viewport orientation to landscape on the iPhone or the simulator. I tried the following two methods within my config.xml.

`<preference name="orientation" value="default" />`

`<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />`

I am still not able to use the app in landscape mode. (Of course I disabled any rotation locks on my iPhone.)

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried it and it worked fine. Be sure to set the correct options in XCode like this:
[image: XCode portrait changes]

Before you do this you build a clear Project like this ->

1. `cordova create OrientationChange com.example.com OrientationChange`
2. `cd OrientationChange`
3. `cordova platform add ios`
4. `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console` (you don't need this for the orientation change but it's useful for debugging).
5. `cordova build`

Run the Project in XCode (6.3 is the actual version) and give it a try - it should work!

Let me know if you need further help!

Comment: You’re right, I had to edit the device orientation options within Xcode and now it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As the user above stated, you can simply change it within your Xcode project. However, this seems like a bug that has yet to be fixed with Cordova, since the Orientation setting is supposed to set this per the Cordova documentation.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File

I've run into the problem where a published project had to be rebuilt and I forgot to modify these settings in the Xcode project itself, resulting in the published project not having rotation capabilities. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Looks like this issue is fixed with Cordova 5.4.1. I can now use the "all" orientation preference to support all orientations.

Answer (score 1):

Specific to cordova :

> File called appDelegate.m in ios where is orientation is set for
>   complete ios app in code just change that orientation and that will
>   fix the issue, tested on IOS9