# Cordova : iOS and iPad stuck in portrait mode

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad

I added the following to the config.xml in the root

`<preference name="orientation" value="default" />`

but it seems to have no effect, the app is stuck in portrait mode. I also made sure to  disable orientation lock.

Any ideas ?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <widget id="com.ameba.mobile.api" android-versionCode="5" version="1.4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
            <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
            <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    .......
            <content src="index.html" />
            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
            <access origin="*" />
            <platform name="android">
                <allow-intent href="market:*" />
            </platform>
            <platform name="ios">
                <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
                <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
                <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
            </platform>
        </widget>
```

Comment: This helped : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549782/phonegap-device-orientation-under-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug, default orientation for iPad should be all orientations

Anyway, if you want to have all orientations on iPhone and iPad, you can use the "all" orientation value

```
<preference name="orientation" value="all" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To expend on jcesarmobile's answer, the 'default' flag strips down all orientation preferences from your project and for iOS this means that XCode will not repopulate your plist with all values, but instead leave it blank.

[See the config.xml readme.md](https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/blob/676f107163d17c70cfa528ed13583dc8dcd8f5d2/docs/en/edge/config_ref/index.md)

For my particular project, I had to wrap this in a platform tag to avoid prepare errors:

```
<platform name="ios">
  <preference name="Orientation" value="all" />
</platform>
```